# Vue v-model data is from ajax undefined value

Tags: vue.js

I used the vue 2. I had a data from ajax, this is my code example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" v-model="siteInfo.siteId">
        <input type="input" class="form-control" v-model="siteInfo.info.name">
        <input type="input" class="form-control" v-model="siteInfo.accountData.name">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Site',
    data() {
        return {
            siteInfo: {},
            /* siteInfoName: '', */
        }
    },
    /*computed: {
        siteInfoName: function() {
            return siteInfo.info.name || '';
        },
        ...
    },*/
    methods: {
        getData() {
            // do ajax get data
            this.$http.post('URL', {POSTDATA}).then(response => {
                /*
                   response example
                   { body: 
                       data: {
                           sitdeId: 1,
                           info: { name: 'test'},
                           accountData: { name: 'accountTest'},
                       }
                   }
                */
                this.siteInfo = response.body.data;
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();
    }
}
</script>
```

I got a warring message

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined"

1. I can use `computed` to fix it, but if I had a lot model, I should
   write a lot computed.
2. I should create a lot data for those model?
3. I should not use an object to bind a lot model?

Does it have another solution for this situation? Thanks your help.

Comment: is 'URL' supposed to be like that? Or is it just to hide from SO? Just in case.

Comment: I added the response data samepl

Comment: I just want to know what is the good solution for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the data loads `siteInfo.info` will be `undefined`, so you can't access `name` in the `v-model`:

```
v-model="siteInfo.info.name"
```

Likewise for `siteInfo.accountData.name`.

My suggestion would be to set the initial value of `siteInfo` to `null` and then put a `v-if="siteInfo"` on the main `div`. Alternatively you could put a `v-if` on the individual `input` elements that checks for `siteInfo.info` and `siteInfo.accountData`.

You may also want to consider showing alternative content, such as a load mask, while the data is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be worried about too many v-models - you can do an iteration on the **Object** - like with `Object.entries()`.

```js
Vue.component('list-input-element', {
  props: ['siteLabel', 'siteInfo'],
  template: '<div><label>{{siteLabel}}<input type="input" class="form-control" v-model="siteInfo"></label></div>'
})

new Vue({
  name: 'Site',
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      siteInfo: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      // using mockup data for this example
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json)
          this.siteInfo = json
        })
      // do ajax get data
      /*this.$http.post('URL', {
        POSTDATA
      }).then(response => {
        this.siteInfo = response.body.data;
      })*/
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <list-input-element v-for="siteInfo in Object.entries(siteInfo)" :site-label="siteInfo[0]" :site-info="siteInfo[1]" />
</div>
```

### Rounding up

So, when you do the single file template, use a **computed** value, and return an **Object** from that.

Base your **v-for** on that **computed**, and you'll have no problems.

Something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="input" class="form-control" v-for="infoEl in siteInfoComputed" v-model="infoEl">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Site',
    data() {
        return {
            siteInfo: {},
        }
    },
    computed: {
      siteInfoComputed: function() {
          // you could check for all the keys-values you want here, and handle
          // 'undefined' problem here
          // so, actually you "create" the Object here that you're going to use
          let ret = {}
          // checking if this.siteInfo exists
          if (Object.keys(this.siteInfo).length) ret = this.siteInfo
          return ret
      },
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            // do ajax get data
            this.$http.post('URL', {POSTDATA}).then(response => {
                /*
                   response example
                   { body: 
                       data: {
                           sitdeId: 1,
                           info: { name: 'test'},
                           accountData: { name: 'accountTest'},
                       }
                   }
                */
                this.siteInfo = response.body.data;
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();
    }
}
</script>
```